# How to save and load in panel?

Tags: c#, bitmap, panel, bitmapimage

I want to save image from panel to bitmap and then I want to load the saved image after my Form comes out of minimizing mode.

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(panel1.Width, panel1.Height);
panel1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, panel1.Bounds);
bmp.Save(@"C:\Test");
panel1.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Test");
```

And what event should I use for minimizing event?
P.S. I am a C# beginner.

Comment: Reading between the lines, it seems that your image is "lost" when you minimize and restore your Form?  I'm guessing that you've probably used CreateGraphics() to do your drawing.  Use "e.Graphics" in the Paint() event of your Panel and store the data about what to draw at Class level so it will automatically be redrawn when the Form is restored.  If you show us how you originally created the drawing then we can help you fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED**

*Drawing your panel's contents. This should be done inside its Paint event handler, like this:*

```
private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    using (Pen p = new Pen(Color.Red, 3))
    {
        // get the panel's Graphics instance
        Graphics gr = e.Graphics;

        // draw to panel
        gr.DrawLine(p, new Point(30, 30), new Point(80, 120));
        gr.DrawEllipse(p, 30, 30, 80, 120);
    }
}
```

*Saving your panel's contents as an image. This part should be done somewhere else (for example, when you click on a "Save" button):*

```
private void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     int width = panel1.Size.Width;
     int height = panel1.Size.Height;

     using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height))
     {
         panel1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height));
         bmp.Save(@"C:\testBitmap.jpeg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I only get a white background image, i don't get Graphic I draw with on it using e.drawline()

Comment: here is what I want to do I don't want to redraw my point using onpaint method I want to just save the panel with the drawing I did with mouse and then I can load the saved image with a Load button, the problem I am facing is on save..I don't want to use onpaint method

Comment: thanks your method helps but can I draw image/graphic using a method() using the void panel1_paint